# Multisite custom taxonomy archive issues

Tags: custom-taxonomy, multisite

We are using a WP multisite install.

3 subsites use the same theme, using a custom taxonomy which is defined inside the theme code.

The issue we have is that the archive page for this custom taxonomy does work on 1 subsite but not on 2 others.

Our question:

- Is it possible that the permalink structure causes this although all 3 sites use different domain names?
- In case the above can't be the problem does anyone have suggestions on possible causes of this issue? Or suggestions on where and how to start debugging?

Comment: Have you flushed rewrite rules on all sites after activating the theme?

Comment: Good point...i did try to flush by changing permalink structure but not sure if this is sufficient. Will look into that today

Comment: It should be sufficient, but you have to do this on every single site/blog in your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

This is issue was solved by correctly flushing rewrite rules:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->init(); //important...
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

Comment: You don't do this flushing on every page view, I hope...

Comment: No, just a one time script I executed

Comment: OK, so everything's fine :)